# jhipster import-jdl error in jhipster gateway app when jdl has user entity relationship

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster, spring-webflux, jhipster-gateway

I have generated a Jhipster gateway application using jhipster version 7.6.0. Here is my yo.rc

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "applicationType": "gateway",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "baseName": "demo",
    "blueprints": [],
    "buildTool": "gradle",
    "cacheProvider": "no",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "clientTheme": "litera",
    "clientThemeVariant": "primary",
    "creationTimestamp": 1645612665729,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "devServerPort": 4200,
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "enableGradleEnterprise": false,
    "enableHibernateCache": false,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": true,
    "enableTranslation": false,
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "jhipsterVersion": "7.6.0",
    "jwtSecretKey": "ZGZjMmY2NjBiOGYwNjQxZDE1MzU1MzlkY2VhOWU5ODM0MWFkOWYzZDA2NTcyNTI2ZTgxOTJlYmI2NTY0Y2JjOWNjODdjNWMyNmM4YTZkNTMyNTZhMDhkZTBlNzliYzI5YTE0OWM5ZjExNzc1YjE1YTI5ZWFiNzAzMDVkMTQwYTg=",
    "languages": ["en", "fr"],
    "messageBroker": "kafka",
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "otherModules": [],
    "packageName": "com.demo",
    "pages": [],
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "reactive": true,
    "searchEngine": false,
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "serverSideOptions": ["messageBroker:kafka", "enableSwaggerCodegen:true"],
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "eureka",
    "skipCheckLengthOfIdentifier": false,
    "skipFakeData": false,
    "skipUserManagement": false,
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "websocket": false,
    "withAdminUi": true
  }
}
```

I have a app-jdl.jdl file with the following content

```
entity Blog {
  name String required minlength(3)
  handle String required minlength(2)
}

relationship ManyToOne {
  Blog{user(login)} to User
}
```

when I run `jhipster import-jdl app-jdl.jdl` I get the following error
[image]

What is causing the issue and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your application auth type is

```
"authenticationType": "jwt"
```

check this post it seems its not supported in jwt yet

[Jhipster - JDL studio - relationship to User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60315333/jhipster-jdl-studio-relationship-to-user)